# SubSonic3 - Url.CreateSortLink

Tags: subsonic3

I'm using SubSonic 3.0.0.2 and can't find the Url.CreateSortLink method.

Where is it?  It was in 3.0.0.0.  Has it been dropped?

Comment: I'm thinking it's in the Url.Action as an overload, but there is no documentation to indicate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using AdventureWorks and listing the Employee table.

I got the answer for sorting the columns using v3.0.0.2:

```
<a href='<%= Url.Action("Index", "Employee", new { s = "EmployeeID" }) %>'>Employee ID</a>
```

On the back-end code:

```
string sortBy = Request.QueryString["s"];

IEnumerable<Employee> items = null;

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy))
    items = Employee.GetPaged(pageNumber, pageSize);
else
    items = Employee.GetPaged(sortBy, pageNumber, pageSize);

return View(items);
```